# Integrating Spring MVC , Jquery , Ajax and Tiles

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, apache-tiles

I'm trying to implement an ajax functionality into my weapp, I'm using Spring MVC and Tiles, for Ajax call I'm using jquery.

Everything works fine except ajax functionality

The related code are next:

**Tiles Configuration:**

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView"/>
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/plantilla/plantilla.xml</beans:value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/vistas.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

**My Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "clientes/listarProvincias", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody List<Provincia> listarProvincias(@RequestParam(value = "departamento", required = true)String codigoDepartamento){
    logger.info("Ingresando al Metodo Listar Provincias con Ajax");
    Integer codDep = Integer.parseInt(codigoDepartamento);
    return this.provinciaDAO.listarProvinciaPorDepartamento(codDep);
}
```

**My JSP**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#departamento').change(
            function() {
                $.getJSON('clientes/listarProvincias', {
                    departamento : $(this).val(),
                    ajax : 'true'
                }, function(data) {
                    alert("Ingresando a JSON");
                    var html = '<option value="">Departamento</option>';
                    var len = data.length;
                    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + data[i].name + '">'
                                + data[i].name + '</option>';
                    }
                    html += '</option>';

                    $('#provincias').html(html);
                });
            });
});
</script>
```

**Part of the form**

```
 <p>
                        <label>Departamento</label>
                        <span class="field">
                            <form:select path="departamento.codDpto" id="departamento">
                                <form:option value="" ></form:option>
                                <c:forEach items="${departamentos}" var="departamento">
                                    <form:option value="${departamento.codDpto}">${departamento.descripcion}</form:option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                            <label class="error">
                                <form:errors path="estaReg" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>Provincia</label>
                        <span class="field">
                            <form:select path="provincia.codprovincia" id="provincias">
                                <form:option value="" ></form:option>
                                <c:forEach items="${provincias}" var="provincia">
                                    <form:option value="${provincia.codprovincia}">${provincia.descripcion}</form:option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                            <label class="error">
                                <form:errors path="estaReg" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </p>
```

Google Chomre Tools shows:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sictem/clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=5&ajax=true 404 (No Encontrado)
```

**Logs**

```
    DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter - Requested session ID46A28166F0557A3A00BB916481349AC8 is invalid.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/clientes/listarprovincias'; against '/*'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /clientes/listarProvincias?departamento=6&ajax=true reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need change your controller declaration as well

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "json", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> listJson(@RequestParam String nombre) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        // PAY ATTENTION TO THIS:
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        List<Medico> result = null;
        if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(nombre)) {
            result = Provincia.findProvinciaEntries(0, 10);
        } else result = Provincia.findProvinciaEntries(0, 10);


        // NEED TO CREATE JSON ARRAY
        String data = "{\"items\":" + Provincia.toJsonArray(result) + " }";
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(data, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Hope this help you